# Check if tool is selected in ArcMap

Tags: arcobjects, c#

How to check, if ArcMap custom tool is active? I have MyCustomTool and docWindow. docWindow opens when MyCustomTool is created. When I close docWindow and select another tool (hand - for example), then MyCustomTool again - docWindow doesn't open.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you get can get or set the current tool using iApplication.CurrentTool property. See [here.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002300000037000000) Whether or not this works for custom tools I'm unsure.